# unable to use createCanvas as a global variable?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

- I was trying to run this code but I am getting error for not declaring variables properly.
- I have formatted this code which is previously written using a class but I am getting errors in assigning global variables.
- When I am adding fill in render() function it is getting to both circles but i need to assign blue to only middle circle

```js
let radius = 20;
let theta = 0;
let history = [];
let vel = 0.0;
let particle;


function render(){
      
  let line = createVector(0,0);
  let velocity = createVector();
      translate(60,60);
      circle(center.x,center.y,radius);
      circle(line.x+center.x, line.y+center.y,10); 
      beginShape();
      for(let i=0;i < history.length; i++){
          let pos = history[i];
          noFill();
          fill(0,0,255);
          noStroke();
          circle(pos.x, pos.y,10);
         
      }
      endShape();
  }

  

function update(){
      line.x = radius*cos(theta);
      line.y = radius*sin(theta);
      
      if (mouseIsPressed){
          if (vel < 1.0) {
              vel += 0.001
          }
          center.x += line.x * vel;
          center.y += line.y * vel;
          let v = createVector(center.x, center.y);
          
          let h = history;
          if (h.length == 0 || Math.trunc(h[h.length-1].x) != Math.trunc(v.x) || Math.trunc(h[h.length-1].y) != Math.trunc(v.y)) { 
              history.push(v);
          }
      
      } else{
          vel = 0.0; 
          theta += 0.01;
      } 
  
}



function setup() {
  let can = createCanvas(windowWidth-220, windowHeight-90);  
  let center = createVector(0,0);
  
  can.position(210, 75);

}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  render();
  update();

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: @devnull69 I was trying to modify this code [link](https://editor.p5js.org/harshasatyavardhan/sketches/WPWh600Di). The code is written using a class. but I am trying to remove the class, because I was unable to add another library functions in that class.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are declaring `let can` and `let center` inside a function, so it's only stored locally.

Try defining `let can, center;` at the beginning of your code, and then removing the `let`s inside `function setup()`
Something like:

```
let radius = 20;
let theta = 0;
let history = [];
let vel = 0.0;
let particle;
let can, center; // defined here
...
function setup() {
  // remove let
  can = createCanvas(windowWidth-220, windowHeight-90);  
  center = createVector(0,0);
  
  can.position(210, 75);

}
```

Also, if this is going to be a class, then instead of using global `let`s you should use `this`.

Comment: I am getting this both errors if i try defining let can, center; at the beginning of code `ReferenceError: createCanvas is not defined` , `Cannot access 'can' before initialization `

Comment: Added an example, see if that helps

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem but i am getting another error `annot read property 'x' of undefined `. I am attaching the [link](https://editor.p5js.org/harshasatyavardhan/sketches/KPB1ou3iT) for the code please take a look.

Comment: @harsha If you declare variables outside of a function with `let`, when you assign values to them with a function you need to do so **without** the `let` keyword inside your functions. I.E. do `center = createVector(0,0);` not `let center = createVector(0,0);`. The let keyword should only be used once for the initial declaration unless you specifically want to create a separate variable that only exists in the nested scope and hides the original. Also, *beware*, declaring a variable `line` will make it impossible to use the global p5.js function of same name.